# OpenLdap - usage of "$" style modifier

Tags: ldap, openldap

i just couldn't figure out the usage of "$" sign as per below.

```
access to dn.regex="(.+,)?ou=People,(dc=[^,]+,dc=[^,]+)$"
         attrs=children,entry,uid
    by group.expand="cn=Managers,$2" write
    by users read
    by * auth
```

What does the "$2" refers to?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the second parenthesised group in the regex.